# How to populate an empty small town?

Tags: humans, aliens

My work in progress involves a small town which has been set up in an isolated part of the United States.  The backstory is that some very advanced aliens want to set up an observatory on Earth, to monitor human behavior. They have their own version of the Prime Directive (closer to a scientist's desire to not contaminate a petri dish than a concern for our welfare) and a nearly magical level of technology. They have no difficulty replicating our buildings and civil infrastructure, nor do they worry about detection or intrusion by the indigenous population.  The entire town is concealed holographically and surrounded by a selective emotional induction system (Any unwanted visitors become frightened, thirsty, anxious or whatever emotion best convinces them to leave).

The only problem their leader (me) can't solve is how to initially fill the town with humans without letting them know that the town builders are aliens, and while simultaneously not letting others know of the town's existence.

How do you find a bunch of disconnected individuals (or families) who would happily move into isolation?

By the way, this is all backstory from my current-day story's point of view, so the populating of the town actually occurred back in the 1970s.

Edit : It has occurred to me while creating this question and reading the initial responses, that my mythical little town has a lot in common with the setting for Wayward Pines.  That story used scouts to recruit their future residents.  I'll have to give that possibility more thought.

Comment: How does the rest of the world not know about the town's existence?  There's telephone service, mail service, electricity service, freight delivery, etc. not to mention things like surveying, census taking, and taxation at both the local, state, and national levels.

Comment: Do the aliens need a representative sample of the US population? And how big is this town?

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan, all infrastructure needs (electricity, water, sanitation) are provided for by a "accomplice humans" (who know what is going on) using alien tech in a secure facility which has its own emotional induction defense There are a pair of accomplice truck drivers who bring in supplies several times per week. Mail, phone and later internet are all available but I am planning to use religion, social conditioning & instant gratification of desires (implemented by the aliens) to minimize external interaction. Government embedded accomplises take care of the rest.

Comment: @Otkin, the aliens don't need a representative sample.  They are trying to measure our biological and mental potental, so selection on desired trait rather than gender or ethnic origin would serve their purposes.

Comment: @Otkin,  I forgot to mention it earlier.  I'm targetting about 600 occupants including children.

Comment: I'm not sure that a self-selected sample would accurately reflect "*our biological and mental potential*." It's more likely to reflect the potential of the set of weirdoes willing to move to secretive, suspicious-looking town ( Example: [Homer Simpson](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/You_Only_Move_Twice)). For real data, here's the real-world village of [Mecosta, Michigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecosta,_Michigan), population 400: Impoverished and poorly educated, two churches, two taverns, two gas stations, one elementary school, one auto repair shop, no grocery stores.

Comment: @user535733, Thanks for the example town/village.  That will be very helpful to study for distribution of roles in a limited scale community.  As for the tendency for selection to yield undesirable results, the admissions policies of most of the worlds universities might not agree with your conclusions.  I'm confident that I can craft the right bait to get specific calibers of people for this town.

Comment: I am afraid that selection based on a specific trait will not provide accurate results if you are looking to measure 'our biological and mental potential', especially if 'our' means humanity. Also, depending on the desired trait different methods of recruitment should be used.

Comment: Another series possibly to have a look at is 'A Town Called Eureka'. As Nepene says a company town in the middle of Oregon, nowhere. Protected by an electromagnetic shield and the US DoD.

Comment: Isn't the Chinese government facing a similar problem?  (i.e. they built out gleaming new cities which then sit empty for a long time because nobody wants to live there, because there's nobody else living there)

Answer (score 23):

## Have a [Company town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_town#United_States)

Pick some industry like manufacturing or mining or whatever. Then you can offer people absurd wages to come to your town and do whatever job so that you can study them. This offers several advantages over religion.

## You can get anyone who wants money.

An alien race can probably make a lot of cash. You can as such get whatever desired traits you want from people by just offering them a dream job and loads of cash.

## The government has an easy answer to any abuses or medical experiments you do.

You can hire a lobbyist to impress on politicians that your town is valuable and good, and you can incorporate the town so you control the hospitals, police, and mental health. As such, you can do whatever and people will just assume you're a controlling corporation, not an alien race.

This also minimizes chances of the military or the government finding you and worrying about an invasion, which would be a massive prime directive violation. They know you're there, and they don't care so long as you pay your taxes.

## You can control who goes in and out.

You control the police, and whatever local authorities you've made. As such, any stubborn people can simply be ordered by the mayor to be removed, even if they resist emotional impulses.

The best way to not be noticed is to be boring. There's no shortage of companies in remote places doing whatever they want to be employees. Be part of the crowd, and be invisible.

Comment: Interesting option.  Hiding a unbelievable evil (aliens) behind a much more believable evil (corporations).  Definitely worth consideration.  Thanks!

Comment: Ooooh! This is the most sensible solution to the problems I bring up in my answer! I love it! +1

Comment: +1 Note that the aliens can also control education by establishing schools. Unfortunately this is in Dutch only, but [Philips did that for about 60 years](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philips_Bedrijfsschool)

Comment: That was also done in the [James Bond novel Dr. No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._No_(novel)), where workers were hired to the island with a high salary and kept happy. Afterwards, a dragon story was created to keep others out of the island.

Comment: Yeah. You want there to be a hidden truth for people who investigate you to discover. The hidden truth being that the real evil is capitalism is a great distraction for the real evil being aliens.

Answer (score 11):

**A "movement" moves in.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antelope,_Oregon

> In the early 1980s, members of the Rajneesh movement moved in and
> effectively took over the government of the city by outnumbering the
> original residents with new voter registrations. On September 18,
> 1984, a vote was held and the city was renamed to "Rajneesh, Oregon".
> By 1985, after several of the Rajneesh movement leaders were
> discovered to have been involved in criminal behavior (including a
> mass food poisoning attack and an aborted plot to assassinate a U.S.
> Attorney), their guru left the country as part of a negotiated
> settlement of federal immigration fraud charges, and the Rajneesh
> commune collapsed. On November 6, 1985, the city voted to rename
> itself back to Antelope.

The town was taken over by a cult.  It makes for fascinating reading.  It is still not clear how many people lived there or exactly what all they were doing.  If you come at it from a Laird Barron-type horror perspective it is pretty wild.

So too your city.  There is nothing wrong with being a member of a splinter religion or following a charismatic leader.  There are many of these in the US and most are not the Branch Davidians.  Your people are a peaceful sect that want to do their peaceful things.  They have fields and crafts and are regulars at the farmers market in the nearby city where they make their money.  They have some pamphlets too for interested people.  It is a good cover.  Maybe it is legitimately who and what they are.

Comment: Nice!  I think this will work too.  I see the "zealots" as a layer between the "accomplices" who know of the Alien's existence and the rest of the population, who although enjoying friendship with these peaceful believers, have their own reasons for moving into isolation.  So three relatively peaceful factions, the accomplices, the zealots and the recruited.  Three levels of "in-the-know".  I like how this is coming together. Thanks!

Comment: If it were an episode of The Outer Limits, the aliens would be hiding themselves among the cultists.  At the end of the episode it turns out that the beliefs of the cult were grounded in reality, and something shows up.  It is very much not the aliens.  But it is interested in them.

Comment: It can be non-religious too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Oaks_Community,_Virginia

Answer (score 3):

> AAA Do you want to live in the place of your dreams? We are looking for you.

In those years people went to mass gatherings like Woodstock, the various protests in Washington DC and all the rest without social media spreading the word.

You have just to spread a tam tam to throw a bait, and test the people who respond to see if they fit your selection criteria. If they do, when they get close to the barrier you switch it off and let them in, if they don't you don't switch the barrier off and let them be scared away.

Comment: Excellent!  The defenses become the filter!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Your aliens must be in cahoots with a government, local or national**

Even in the 70s, towns were hard-pessed to exist without infrastructure.

Some of this can be dealt with by your aliens, but others won't. For a town to survive, things must be brought *into* and taken *out of* the community:

- Food
- Electricity/Natural Gas/Fuels of all kinds
- Water (in terms of santizing chemicals, pump parts, state inspections...)
- Sewer (even if sewer treatment is on-site, there's chemicals... parts... inspections...)
- Raw materials including wood, metal, and fabricated materials such as tools, parts, etc.

I could go on, but the reality is that no town (at least in the 70s) is truly isolated. Even communes, unless living in what the rest of us would call squalor, were not truly isolated. Trucks had to come in, telephone lines had to go out. People had televisions and radio, and the Federal Government cared an awful lot whether or not they paid their taxes.

And let's not forget some poor schmuck who decided to get on their bicycle and ride along a lonely road only to discover an entire community, which said rider immediately writes about in their favorite [underground press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_press). And such presses existed in great numbers in the 70s. It was kinda their hayday — the "social media" of that generation.

So, let's consider an option:

**Let's consider Russia's "[closed cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city)"**

> A closed city or closed town is a settlement where travel or residency restrictions are applied so that specific authorization is required to visit or remain overnight. Such places may be sensitive military establishments or secret research installations that require much more space or freedom than is available in a conventional military base. There may also be a wider variety of permanent residents, including close family members of workers or trusted traders who are not directly connected with clandestine purposes.

> Many closed cities existed in the Soviet Union from the late 1940s until its dissolution in 1991. After 1991, a number of them still existed in the CIS countries, especially in Russia. In modern Russia, such places are officially known as "closed administrative-territorial formations."

The wonderful thing about closed cities is, because they exist with the support of the government, *all those nasty problems I just discussed don't exist.* The protecting government is ensuring that all the proverbial *gazinta* and *gazoutas* happen without anyone asking, "Why's there a city there in the first place?"

**And once you have a government lined up to protect the city...**

The answer of how to get people to populate it is trivial. The government can advertise on the grounds of settler's rights, or give out invitations to serve a purpose, or simply extend invitations to existing government employees, whose jobs are then refilled in the normal way. It's easy at that point.

Comment: You are making me think that I should push the formation of the town back a few decades, maybe to the chaos following the end of WWII, back to a time when validation of official appearing documents was a manual process involving a telephone and some clerks.  What I want is for bureaucracy and laziness to take the place of a totalitarian regime in creating this softly closed city.  As for government collusion, that has been a given from the very start.  When your first contact dialog starts with "We come in judgement", governments tend to obey.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I get it, but you're stuck with the infrastructure problem all the way back to at least 1880 and more likely 1840. A truck (or wagon) load of food may only be an issue of paying for it, but a truck (or wagon) load of machined parts involves a chain of documentation that's really hard to avoid. People have been keeping tallies of everything from trade to taxes back to ancient China and Egypt. That paper trail is your real problem (assuming that someone in the town wanting to get married at Niagra Falls isn't...).

Comment: I've covered the infrastructure shortfalls in replies to other comments but in summary, alien tech and human collaborators handle most of the issues and a pair of semi-trucks, driven by collaborators make bi-weekly trips to a warehouse near a major city.  That warehouse is kept stocked with anything the residents request through by warehouse employees funded by the aliens' significant economic resources.  I grew up in the Bahamas during the 60's and all our supplies arrived by ship, so this part will work.  As for masking the paper trail, that is what corporations are for.

Comment: "Human collaborators" = government. Stocking a single warehouse means your population is less than 20 people (I own a retail store, so I, too, have experience with the supply chain). But, not to argue, I'm just pointing out that the problems I mention are realistic, hence my answer.

Comment: Also, the people aren't prisoners.  They are allowed to travel but are socially conditioned not to talk about their town of origin or to bring anyone back with them when they return.  Many of the second generation have been trained at Universities far from the town.  Some come back, others don't, but none every talk about their upbringing or bring stragglers home.

Comment: Many thanks!  I'll consider your answer as I formalize this backstory.  What I can fix through the scale and power of the aliens, I will.  What I can't fix...  I will just hope that most of my readers lack your supply chain experience.  
Thanks Again!

Comment: You need less government involvment if the town people are native americans in the reservation, someone like menonites/amishes or hippes. And less resources too. Because they all tend to live a modest self-sustaining life.

Comment: @user28434 That sounds like an excellent answer rather than a question asking for clarification about my answer. Actually, it looks a lot like Wllk's answer....

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact, yep, I've added comment to Wilk's answer too. And haven't used it as answer myself, because it's too similar.

Answer (score 2):

**You already have the tools**

You've mentioned an Emotional Induction field of sorts.

All you need to do is find people who fit your needs and coax them into moving to your town via inducted emotional responses.
If they see the name of the place, induce a sense of longing or homesickness to goad them into uprooting themselves and moving there.

Do this for enough people and your town will soon be populated.

It may be necessary to mess with people's memories to suggest that it's not unusual to arrive in a largely unpopulated town and (sometimes literally) set up shop.

It could also be worth abducting an entire Smalltown-USA from somewhere nearby and moving them into your town with some liberal memory-modification.

Truthfully though, it may be better to start with an existing town and modify it to suit your needs rather than build a whole new one.
As others have commented, tying a whole artificial new town to the infrastructure of a nation without anyone noticing anything amiss would be.. a challenge in the extreme.

Comment: Retrofitting an existing town has its merits.  Most notably it is more believable than my approach.  Thanks!